# How to make softer frozen whipped cream?

Tags: frozen, whipped-cream

I recently found out that a few decades ago frozen whipped cream was a thing and my mom liked it. It was similar to normal whipped cream only a bit harder frozen (but still softer than ice cream) and could last for ages in the freezer.

Now I tried to make some for her and it was good, however mine is always too hard while frozen compared to what she loved. When it warms up it is fine and personally I don't find it too hard but whatever.

The process I use is simple, mix cream (36%), some sugar and vanilla extract whip until done and either freeze in one piece or in smaller ones.

Any ideas how to make it softer while frozen and ideally hard when it thaws? I've thought about adding some milk (it's to late to buy one with less fat) to reduce the fat content or not whipping it as much. Do you think any would work and if so which would you recommend?

Comment: Have you tried varying the amount of sugar?

Comment: I put in one bag of vanilla sugar and one table spoon of normal per 250ml. Are you suggesting less or more? Less makes it not sweet and disgusting so would just exchange one problem for another. More I can try, how much do you suggest? I also have some fake sweeteners which will dissolve in water? How about that?

Comment: I really don't know, otherwise I would write an answer, but my thinking is if this was a commercial product back then, it very likely had plenty of sugar in it. So I wondered if experimenting with just a little bit *more* sugar than you normally would add might make a softer product. Sugar does seem to *add* to the liquid content when mixed with liquidy stuff, rather than drying it up as flour or other dry things would, and it also seems to inhibit freezing (think of frozen lemonade mix or grape juice concentrate: I think it's the sugar that keeps it so soft in the freezer)

Comment: I called her and asked if she'r rather have that which I can't guarantee will be like it was or if she'd rather have some whipped cream with a Nutella like spread and walnuts I can guarantee will be good.. She picked the latter. And it is (or mostly was) awesome.

Comment: But thanks for the help I'll do more experiments and get it right one of these days.

Comment: I know that there's a no churn ice cream that uses condensed milk and heavy cream, it seems to stay pretty soft, you might want to give that a try.

Comment: Is it possible that when your mother enjoyed it in the past it simply came from a less cold freezer?

Comment: _More_ fat, not less, will make it softer while frozen.

Answer (score 2):

My advice is to use [inverted sugar](http://www.wikihow.com/Invert-Sugar)

Inverted sugar helps to avoid crystallization and the frozen cream will be substantially smoother.

Comment: Can you use corn syrup?

Comment: Corn syrup, contains maltose, while inverted sugar contains glucose and fructose. They have different properties and different nutritional content. Inverted Sugar cannot be substituted with corn syrup in this application (avoiding crystallization of frozen cream)